# Pygame image not moving when keys are pressed

Tags: python, pygame

The update section of Player class doesn't work when I run the program. It displays the picture, but I can't get it to move right or left when the keys are pressed. It stays motionless. What am I missing?

```
import pygame
import random
import os

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

display_width = 460
display_height = 600
FPS = 30

#colors
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (40,60))
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = display_width/2
        self.rect.bottom = display_height - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.speedx = -7
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.speedx = 7
                    self.rect.x += self.speedx



#image loading
player_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, "malirozi.png")).convert()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

#game loop
running = True
while running:
    #Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    #Logic
    all_sprites.update()

    #Draw / render
    game_display.fill(black)
    all_sprites.draw(game_display)
    #after drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I'm guessing your event handling logic is not right.  Normally, you should have just one "top level" loop calling `pygame.event.get()` that then passes events down to the objects that care about them.  As is, I'm guessing your arrow key presses are swallowed by the loop looking for `pygame.QUIT`.  Alternatively, perhaps what you're after in the `update()` function is to check and see what keys are currently depressed rather than looking for key up / down events.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `pygame.event.get`  consumes all events in the queue.
That means that it should be done ina  single place - when you do
`for event in pygame.event.get():` 
in the main boyd, just bellow the while loop, you swallow all
`keydown` events that might be read inside your `update` method.

The remedy to this is to *ensure* you make your calls to `pygame.event.get`  in just a single point in your code. You can, for example, append the unhandled events to a list, and pass that list as a parameter to your update method - there you check these events instead of calling `pygame.event.get` again.

Also, note that the line `self.rect.x += self.speedx` should be outside the `if` statement.

```
...
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
       ...
       self.events = []
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        for event in self.events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.speedx = -7
                if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.speedx = 7
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
...
while running:
    #Events
    events = []
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            events.append(event)
    player.events = events
    #Logic
    all_sprites.update()
...
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your event handling is in two different places, and pygame can only run one event handler at a time. I assume from your code that you only want your guy to move 7 pixels once each time is pressed. If you want him to keep moving, you'll need to add more

```
import pygame
import random
import os

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

display_width = 460
display_height = 600
FPS = 30

#colors
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

img_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'img')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (40,60))
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = display_width/2
        self.rect.bottom = display_height - 10
        self.speedx = 0


#image loading
player_img = pygame.image.load("guy.png").convert()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

#game loop
running = True
while running:
    #Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.speedx = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.speedx = 7
        player.rect.x += player.speedx
    #Logic
    all_sprites.update()
    player.rect.centerx += player.speedx
    print(player.speedx)

    #Draw / render
    game_display.fill(black)
    all_sprites.draw(game_display)
    #after drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```